# unable to store .txt file in root directory

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I'm learning web security, and I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to save a .txt file in the root directory. It's actually a wordlist for feroxbuster.

While installing it, I saved the file to the **Documents** directory because I didn't see an option for the **root** directory. Since the file isn't in the root directory, the code refuses to run.

`./feroxbuster -u https://portswigger.net/web-security/information-disclosure/exploiting/lab-infoleak-on-debug-page -w common.txt`
this is my code!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you provide absolute paths instead of relative ones? (E. g. if you're in the home directory, the "prefix" would be `~` or `$HOME`.) Then it'd be clearer whether this depended on the path you're at or the directory you're in.

Answer (score 1):

As [user-id-14900042](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/471115/user-id-14900042) suggests, you need to use absolute paths here. You also need to execute your command with root privileges, which would result in

```bash
sudo ./feroxbuster -u https://portswigger.net/web-security/information-disclosure/exploiting/lab-infoleak-on-debug-page -w /common.txt
```

or

```bash
./feroxbuster -u https://portswigger.net/web-security/information-disclosure/exploiting/lab-infoleak-on-debug-page -w common.txt
sudo mv common.txt /
```

assuming your executing user has root privileges.

Just in case of confusion: The **root directory** is located at `/`. The **home directory** is `$HOME`, which is `/home/[yourUserName]` normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **really** intended read from `common.txt` or save its result on the root directory, prefix path with `/`, like `/common.txt` or `/output.txt`. You will require "root" previledges to do it (thanks @AdminBee for pointing this; You do not have it especially you are using Ubuntu, Debian, or enabled `sudo` command instead of root account). To acquire it, usually switch your account or use `sudo` command. Please consult by `man` command, other question, or guide on your system to how you can.

If you have enabled `sudo` and `tee` command, I recommend use following snippet (which executes `feroxbuster` as your account, and write output as root):

```bash
./feroxbuster --whatever-options | sudo tee /output.txt >/dev/null
```

Comment: You  may want to mention that this requires running the commands with `root` privileges (which the OP, being "new to linux", might not be aware of).